# Error in compilation in procedure in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am new to oracle.So,I am creating a procedure which has all features of insert,update,delete and select method.So when I hit the compilation button then the result is:

```
Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
```

But i am unable to see where is the mistake I did.My table is:

[image]

Now the procedure I tried is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OT.ALL_CRUD_PERSON(DATA1 VARCHAR2,
ID PERSON.ID%TYPE,
NAME PERSON.NAME%TYPE,
AGE  PERSON.AGE%TYPE,
R_C OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS 

CURSOR CUR IS
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM OT.PERSON;
BEGIN
IF DATA1='INSERT' THEN
INSERT INTO OT.PERSON(ID,NAME,AGE) VALUES (CUR,NAME,AGE);
END IF;


IF DATA1='UPDATE' THEN
UPDATE OT.PERSON SET NAME=NAME,AGE=AGE WHERE ID=ID;
END IF;

IF DATA1='DELETE' THEN
DELETE FROM OT.PERSON WHERE ID=ID;
END IF;

IF DATA1='SELECT' THEN
OPEN R_C FOR
SELECT * FROM OT.PERSON;
END IF;

END;
/
```

Also,I want to ask is it the good process to put all the functionality in same procedure?

Comment: Type `show errors` or query `user_errors` to see the errors.  If you're using SQL Developer, there will also be a window that shows you the compilation errors.  I'd seriously question the wisdom of creating a single procedure that does all CRUD operations-- that's going to be unwieldy to work with.  If your goal on the `insert` is to insert a row with the next `id` value, use a sequence, don't use a `max(id)` (which won't work because that's not how to reference a cursor and because you'd be inserting a duplicate value).  Use a sequence.  And don't name parameters the same thing as columns.

Comment: i solved the error now can u give me idea how to execute INSERT statement inside the procedure.. What should i need to pass parameters here EXEC OT.ALL_CRUD_PERSON()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1

```
INSERT INTO PERSON(ID,NAME,AGE) VALUES (CUR,NAME,AGE);
```

This will result in a

Error(19,41): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CUR": invalid identifier

Perhaps should be

```
INSERT INTO PERSON(ID,NAME,AGE) VALUES (ID,NAME,AGE);
```

That at least will compile without errors.

Looks like you're using Toad...I know if you use SQL Developer it will automatically show you the Errors whenever you compile PL/SQL with compiler feedback.

Also, ask yourself this question - do you want due to a bug, for a call to do an UPDATE to accidentally do a DELETE?

I would suggest you break these operations out to individual functions/procedures - and tie them together using a PACKAGE.

Comment: yes i am using toad .. which is the better option to use?

Comment: I would only recommend you to use what Oracle gives you for free, but I'm a bit biased in my position

Comment: @KarkiAshwin - i revised my answer, to your 'good to use all ops in same procedure' I would have to say no

Comment: i tried to execute insert statement using EXEC OT.ALL_CRUD_PERSON('INSERT',null,'keran',10,R_C); but it is saying  ORA-06550: line 1, column 51:
PLS-00201: identifier 'R_C' must be declared.. what should i pass for refcursor?

Comment: @KarkiAshwin once you have your code compiled and executing...you're ready for your 2nd question on SO. start a new question and show us the code you're executing, the errors you get back, and of course include the source code/table ddl/and test data you're using.

Comment: can u give me idea how to execute INSERT statement inside the procedure.. What should i need to pass parameters here EXEC OT.ALL_CRUD_PERSON()?